# Windows Store App OEM keys on KeyDow

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime

I'm writing a Windows Store app, and for the functions to work properly I need to handle the OEM keys for +,-,*,/,?,! Etc. in a KeyDown event handler. But the VirtualKey class doesn't have these keys included and I couldn't find any reference that could help. How can I identify these keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **not** try to translate virtual keystrokes yourself.  This will not come to a good end on machines with a non-standard keyboard layout.  Like the other two billion in the rest of the world.  That was something that you could possibly ignore in desktop apps with a limited distribution but no longer in a Store app that's sold across the planet.  Your app will probably not pass the Store validation when you try anyway.

Not sure why you are doing this but the CoreWindow.CharacterReceived event tends to be hard to find.  Which is what you'll need to get a reliable translation.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the CoreWindow seems to be quite a slippery one :) I'm not stupid enough to try to translate those keystrokes myself, don't worry - if I were, I would have just done it already.